# retrieving collection of records from an entity in dynamic crm using REST and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, dynamics-crm

Looking to retrieve all accounts from the account entity and show this in an alert box using an ajax call to the Service OrganizationData.svc.

This ajax call works fine with a post. as in, adding an account to the set of accounts. Retrieving all the accounts though using a GET. im getting trouble

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://testCrm/MYORG/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet",
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        //Specifying this header ensures that the results will be returned as JSON.             
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
             if ((data.d != null) && (data.d.length > 0)) {        
              alert(data.d) 
                }
             else { alert("error!"); }                                 
    },
    error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               }
});
```

});

I am getting an error pop up, so I'm guessing no data is being returned.

Comment: are you sure this domain "http://testCrm/MYORG/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet" to which u r making ur ajax request and the one where the page with jQuery code are same.

Comment: thats not the Domain, but cant really use my company domain name on here so for instance im using the above.

Comment: if the domain to which you are making ur ajax request and the one which is making the ajax are different, then its a cross domain request in that case you have to make dataType=jsonp, in your ajax request also ur server should return proper json data.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try this

change this `dataType: "json"`, to `dataType: "jsonp"`

**or**

open firebug (install if you don't have done it yet) and see what error message its showing, u may need to switch to NET tab in firebug if you are making a cross-domain request, which i think you are doing.